# Examing Values from xml-field in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to get some data out of an xml-field.
The special problem is the xml-field itself.

The xml-field is build that way:

```
<UseAnsw>
  <User User="3" Answ="N" />
  <User User="2" Answ="N" />
  <User User="7" Answ="N" />
  <User User="5" Answ="N" />
  <User User="1" Answ="N" />
</UseAnsw>
```

The Sql table has also a column with the User who posted a question.
What I need to do is, count how often a User answered questions.

As an Example:

```
use_ID    use_PostingUser     use_UseAnsw
00001     2                   <UseAnsw>
                                  <User User="3" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="1" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="7" Answ="N" />
                              </UseAnsw>
00002     4                   <UseAnsw>
                                  <User User="2" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="1" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="3" Answ="N" />
                              </UseAnsw>
00003     1                   <UseAnsw>
                                  <User User="3" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="5" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="8" Answ="N" />
                              </UseAnsw>
```

The Result out of that example that i look for would be:

```
User   AnswersGiven
1      2
2      1
4      0
```

I hope someone understands what I am trying and is able to help me (an sql-beginner, especially when it comes to xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand, how your count works, but this might push you to the right path:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(use_ID VARCHAR(100),use_PostingUser INT,use_UseAnsw XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('00001',2,'<UseAnsw>
                                  <User User="3" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="1" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="7" Answ="N" />
                              </UseAnsw>')
,('00002',4,'<UseAnsw>
                                  <User User="2" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="1" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="3" Answ="N" />
                              </UseAnsw>')
,('00003',1,'<UseAnsw>
                                  <User User="3" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="5" Answ="N" />
                                  <User User="8" Answ="N" />
                              </UseAnsw>');
```

This query will return *all data*

```
SELECT use_ID,use_postingUser
      ,Usr.value('@User','int') AS AttribUser
      ,Usr.value('@Answ','varchar(max)') AS AttribAnsw
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY use_UseAnsw.nodes('/UseAnsw/User') AS One(Usr)
```

Here I use the same approach to return the column `use_postingUser` and its count of `User` elements (actually of the equally named attribute)

```
SELECT use_postingUser
      ,COUNT(Usr.value('@User','int')) AS CountAttribUser
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY use_UseAnsw.nodes('/UseAnsw/User') AS One(Usr)
GROUP BY use_PostingUser
```

Hope this helps...

## UPDATE

Still I don't understand your logic, but this might come closer:

The `CTE` "AllData" provides the list of all data (as before)

In the final `SELECT` the count of answers for each user according to the User's number *within* the XML is counted. This is OK for 1,2 and 4 (zero==non existent), but there are more IDs you did not mention in your expected output...

If you need all IDs dsiplayed (the 4 with a zero) you'll need a list of all users and a `LEFT JOIN` to the XML's data...

```
WITH AllData AS
(
    SELECT use_ID,use_postingUser
          ,Usr.value('@User','int') AS AttribUser
          ,Usr.value('@Answ','varchar(max)') AS AttribAnsw
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY use_UseAnsw.nodes('/UseAnsw/User') AS One(Usr)
)
SELECT AttribUser
      ,COUNT(*) AS CountAttribUser
FROM AllData
GROUP BY AttribUser
```

### UPDATE 2

According to Y.B's comment it might be this: (use the declared table variable from above)

```
WITH AllData AS
(
    SELECT use_ID,use_postingUser
          ,Usr.value('@User','int') AS AttribUser
          ,Usr.value('@Answ','varchar(max)') AS AttribAnsw
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY use_UseAnsw.nodes('/UseAnsw/User') AS One(Usr)
)
SELECT DistinctUsers.use_PostingUser
      ,COUNT(AllData.AttribUser) AS CountAttribUser
FROM @tbl AS DistinctUsers
LEFT JOIN AllData ON DistinctUsers.use_PostingUser=AllData.AttribUser
GROUP BY DistinctUsers.use_PostingUser
```

Comment: I think the list of users is taken from the source table only and not the XML.